# JSON data extraction using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle

We are on Oracle DB version 19.2. We are trying to use JSON data set very first time and have no experience working with it. We are reading the Oracle documentation related to JSON but found it very hard to follow and understand. We need help to query the data from JSON file that have elements that are part of Nested arrays in side the JSON objects. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

**Here is a JSON file for reference**

```
{

"accountDetails": {

"accountName": "My Account",

"custodianAccount": "My AccountNumber",

"startDate": "220150615",

"endDate": "20230703",

"marketValue": {

"currencyCode": "CAD",

"amount": 737995.96

},

"performance": [

{

"periodLabel": "Inception-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 0.03523584423021675,

"twrrGof": 0.04128811745224015,

"periodStart": "20150616",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

},

{

"periodLabel": "Quarter-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 7.559920027098155,

"twrrGof": 7.559924692275288,

"periodStart": "20230701",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

}

],

},

"sleeves": {

"sleeveDetails": [

{

"sleeveName": "Sleeve1",

"inceptionDate": "20210318",

"marketValue": {

"currencyCode": "CAD",

"amount": 154312.67

},

"performance": [

{

"periodLabel": "Inception-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 1.59171883177918061,

"twrrGof": 0.09171883177918061,

"periodStart": "20210319",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

},

{

"periodLabel": "Quarter-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 1.503752211169898434,

"twrrGof": 5.53752211169898434,

"periodStart": "20230701",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

}

],

},

{

"sleeveName": "Sleeve2",

"inceptionDate": "20210825",

"marketValue": {

"currencyCode": "CAD",

"amount": 262423.86

},

"performance": [

{

"periodLabel": "Inception-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 2.53041295906685626,

"twrrGof": 0.03041295906685626,

"periodStart": "20210826",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

},

{

"periodLabel": "Quarter-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 2.4019374838543011474,

"twrrGof": 0.0019374838543011474,

"periodStart": "20230701",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

}

],

},

{

"sleeveName": "Sleeve3",

"inceptionDate": "20151008",

"marketValue": {

"currencyCode": "CAD",

"amount": 321259.43

},

"performance": [

{

"periodLabel": "Inception-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 3.5362634897972308,

"twrrGof": 5.562634897972308,

"periodStart": "20151009",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

},

{

"periodLabel": "Quarter-to-Date",

"twrrNof": 3.511802131625067158,

"twrrGof": 5.5011802131625067158,

"periodStart": "20230701",

"periodEnd": "20230703"

}

],

},

]

}

}
```

**Output to JSON column mapping :**

- accountName = accountDetails.accountName
- custodianAccount = accountDetails.custodianAccount
- accountMarketValue = accountDetails.marketValue.amount
- account_twrrNof_Inception-to-Date = accountDetails.performance.twrrNof (where periodLabel='Inception-to-Date')
- account_twrrNof_Quarter-to-Date = accountDetails.performance.twrrNof (where periodLabel='Quarter-to-Date')
- sleeveName = sleeves.sleeveDetails.sleeveName
- sleeveMarketValue = sleeves.sleeveDetails.marketValue.amount
- sleeve_twrrNof_Inception-to-Date = sleeves.sleeveDetails.performance.twrrNof (where periodLabel='Inception-to-Date')
- sleeve_twrrNof_Quarter-to-Date = sleeves.sleeveDetails.performance.twrrNof (where periodLabel='Quarter-to-Date')

**Note ,**

- for columns account_twrrNof_
  I have kept only 2 columns here for simplicity purpose , but there 8 different performance number for account , so when we read value for twrrNof, we also need to know which time period it is for, for example mapping it with periodLabel='Inception-to-Date' means this twrrNof value is account_twrrNof_Inception-to-Date.
  There is only 1 account expected in the JSON file.
- for columns sleeve_twrrNof_
  Same like account level performance, I have kept only 2 columns here for simplicity purpose , but there 8 different performance number for each sleeve, so when we read value for twrrNof, we also need to know which time period it is for, for example mapping it with periodLabel='Inception-to-Date' means this twrrNof value is sleeve_twrrNof_Inception-to-Date.
  also account may have 1 or more sleeves in the file , so there may be at least 1 or many sleeves and related performance in the JSON file.

We are very new on querying JSON, we got to fetch basic details for account using JSON_VALUE and tried using JSON_TABLE as well, but not able to fetch the nested values as expected.

**Expected Query output**
here is how we want our query output to look like when we read data from above JSON
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCuEN.jpg)

Comment: your json is not valid, see jsonlint,  and what you need is json_zable see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-0172660F-CE29-4765-BF2C-C405BDE8369A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix your JSON so that it is valid then you can use:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$'
         COLUMNS
           accountName
             VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.accountDetails.accountName',
           custodianAccount
              VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.accountDetails.custodianAccount',
           accountMarketValue
              NUMBER        PATH '$.accountDetails.marketValue.amount',
           account_twrrNof_Inception_to_Date
              VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.accountDetails.performance[*]?(@.periodLabel=="Inception-to-Date").twrrNof',
           account_twrrNof_Quarter_to_Date
              VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.accountDetails.performance[*]?(@.periodLabel=="Quarter-to-Date").twrrNof',
           NESTED PATH '$.sleeves.sleeveDetails[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             sleeveName 
               VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.sleeveName',
             sleeveMarketValue
               NUMBER PATH '$.marketValue.amount',
             sleeve_twrrNof_Inception_to_Date
               VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.performance[*]?(@.periodLabel=="Inception-to-Date").twrrNof',
             sleeve_twrrNof_Quarter_to_Date
               VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.performance[*]?(@.periodLabel=="Quarter-to-Date").twrrNof'
           )
       ) j;
```

Which for the (valid) sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value CLOB CHECK (value IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES (
'{"accountDetails":{"accountName":"My Account","custodianAccount":"My AccountNumber","startDate":"220150615","endDate":"20230703","marketValue":{"currencyCode":"CAD","amount":737995.96},"performance":[{"periodLabel":"Inception-to-Date","twrrNof":0.03523584423021675,"twrrGof":0.04128811745224015,"periodStart":"20150616","periodEnd":"20230703"},{"periodLabel":"Quarter-to-Date","twrrNof":7.559920027098155,"twrrGof":7.559924692275288,"periodStart":"20230701","periodEnd":"20230703"}]},"sleeves":{"sleeveDetails":[{"sleeveName":"Sleeve1","inceptionDate":"20210318","marketValue":{"currencyCode":"CAD","amount":154312.67},"performance":[{"periodLabel":"Inception-to-Date","twrrNof":1.5917188317791806,"twrrGof":0.09171883177918061,"periodStart":"20210319","periodEnd":"20230703"},{"periodLabel":"Quarter-to-Date","twrrNof":1.5037522111698984,"twrrGof":5.537522111698984,"periodStart":"20230701","periodEnd":"20230703"}]},{"sleeveName":"Sleeve2","inceptionDate":"20210825","marketValue":{"currencyCode":"CAD","amount":262423.86},"performance":[{"periodLabel":"Inception-to-Date","twrrNof":2.5304129590668563,"twrrGof":0.03041295906685626,"periodStart":"20210826","periodEnd":"20230703"},{"periodLabel":"Quarter-to-Date","twrrNof":2.4019374838543013,"twrrGof":0.0019374838543011474,"periodStart":"20230701","periodEnd":"20230703"}]},{"sleeveName":"Sleeve3","inceptionDate":"20151008","marketValue":{"currencyCode":"CAD","amount":321259.43},"performance":[{"periodLabel":"Inception-to-Date","twrrNof":3.5362634897972307,"twrrGof":5.562634897972308,"periodStart":"20151009","periodEnd":"20230703"},{"periodLabel":"Quarter-to-Date","twrrNof":3.511802131625067,"twrrGof":5.501180213162507,"periodStart":"20230701","periodEnd":"20230703"}]}]}}');
```

Outputs:

| ACCOUNTNAME | CUSTODIANACCOUNT | ACCOUNTMARKETVALUE | ACCOUNT_TWRRNOF_INCEPTION_TO_DATE | ACCOUNT_TWRRNOF_QUARTER_TO_DATE | SLEEVENAME | SLEEVEMARKETVALUE | SLEEVE_TWRRNOF_INCEPTION_TO_DATE | SLEEVE_TWRRNOF_QUARTER_TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My Account | My AccountNumber | 737995.96 | 0.03523584423021675 | 7.559920027098155 | Sleeve1 | 154312.67 | 1.5917188317791806 | 1.5037522111698984 |
| My Account | My AccountNumber | 737995.96 | 0.03523584423021675 | 7.559920027098155 | Sleeve2 | 262423.86 | 2.5304129590668563 | 2.4019374838543013 |
| My Account | My AccountNumber | 737995.96 | 0.03523584423021675 | 7.559920027098155 | Sleeve3 | 321259.43 | 3.5362634897972307 | 3.511802131625067 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N_UsEiBf)

Comment: Hi MT0,
Thanks for your response .  
I will review and update. 
Much appreciated.